# search by first name in JSF1.2 + seam

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, jboss, seam

I am trying to make search option by first name in my user list page. Before putting search option in user list page, the list of users page works fine.
After I added code in list.xhtml for search the page shows the error below,
        Exception during request processing:
        Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "/secure/admin/user/customer/customerList.xhtml @70,70 value="#{userByFirstNameAction.firstName}": Property 'firstName' not found on type org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_25"

My list page is : customerList.xhtml

```
    <h:form class="input-list" id="searchUser" style="width:100%;"
        name="searchUser">
        <div class="search_button">
            SEARCH BY FIRST NAME :
            <h:inputText tabindex="1" id="firstName" type="text"
                value="#{userByFirstNameAction.firstName}" required="true">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="20" />
            </h:inputText>
        </div>

        <h:commandButton value="Search" tabindex="2"
            action="#{userByFirstNameAction.retrieveCustomersByFirstName}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
```

userByFirstNameAction.java :

```
    @Name("userByFirstNameAction")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class UserByFirstNameActionImpl implements UserByFirstNameAction {


        private UserTypeEnum userType;

        @In
        private UserService userService;

        //@In(value = "firstName", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private String firstName;

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8282995226262125676L;


        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

            @Override
        public List<User> retrieveCustomersByFirstName(String firstName) {
            //this.userType = UserTypeEnum.CUSTOMER;
            return userService.findByFirst(firstName);      
        }

    }
```

@Jan thanks for your time..

I have put Get/Set for firstname in bean class...

Here for your reference

Interface:

```
    package com.ermms.clrp.user;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.ejb.Local;

    import com.ermms.clrp.dto.user.CLRPUser;
    import com.ermms.clrp.dto.user.User;




    @Local
    public interface UserByFirstNameAction extends Serializable {

        public String initEmployee();

        public String initCustomer();

        public List<User> getEmployeesByFirstName();

        public List<User> getCustomersByFirstName();

        public List<User> retrieveEmployeesByFirstName();

        // public List<User> retrieveCustomersByFirstName();

        public List<User> retrieveCustomersByFirstName(String firstName);
    }
```

Class :

```
    package com.ermms.clrp.user;

    import java.util.List;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    import org.jboss.seam.ScopeType;
    import org.jboss.seam.annotations.AutoCreate;
    import org.jboss.seam.annotations.In;
    import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
    import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Out;

    import com.ermms.clrp.common.enumeration.UserTypeEnum;
    import com.ermms.clrp.dto.user.CLRPUser;
    import com.ermms.clrp.dto.user.User;
    import com.ermms.clrp.service.UserService;



    @Name("userByFirstNameAction")
    @Stateless
    @AutoCreate
    public class UserByFirstNameActionImpl implements UserByFirstNameAction {


        private UserTypeEnum userType;

        @In
        private UserService userService;

        //@In(value = "firstName", scope = ScopeType.CONVERSATION, required = false)
        private String firstName;

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8282995226262125676L;


        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        @Override
        public List<User> getEmployeesByFirstName() {
            this.userType = UserTypeEnum.EMPLOYEE;
            return userService.findByFirstName(firstName, userType);
        }

        @Override
        public List<User> getCustomersByFirstName() {
            this.userType = UserTypeEnum.CUSTOMER;
            return userService.findByFirstName(firstName, userType);        
        }

        @Override
        public List<User> retrieveEmployeesByFirstName() {
            this.userType = UserTypeEnum.EMPLOYEE;
            return userService.findByFirstName(firstName, userType);
        }

        @Override
        public List<User> retrieveCustomersByFirstName(String firstName) {
            //this.userType = UserTypeEnum.CUSTOMER;
            return userService.findByFirst(firstName);      
        }

        public String initEmployee() {      
            return "/secure/admin/user/customer/customerListByFirstName.xhtml";
        }

        public String initCustomer() {
            this.userType = UserTypeEnum.CUSTOMER;
            return "/secure/admin/user/customer/customerListByFirstName.xhtml";
        }
        public UserTypeEnum getUserType() {
            return userType;
        }

        public void setUserType(UserTypeEnum userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the Setter/Getter to the UserByFirstNameAction-Interface?

Comment: OK, it's been a while I worked with SEAM 2.2 but I assume that you call the Stateless Session Bean with the @Name userByFirstNameAction. This is not just a SEAM-POJO but a SLSB in the EJB-Context. So the call goes to the SLSB-Local-Interface UserByFirstNameAction. You declared the getter/setter for the var firstName only in the SLSB-Implementation and not in the Local-IFace. For the SEAM-Validators in your IDE(and for EL itself) it's OK at that moment. But at runtime you get the exception above. The solution is to declare getter and setter in the interface, too.

Comment: Jan,   In my UserByFirstNameAction interface I defined get/set for firstName.... is that I did right thing? also I need to add more get/set for anything in the interface?

Comment: To define the getFirstName and setFirstName(String s) in the Local-IFace should be sufficient.

Comment: Jan, Thakns for your help.. its working and the error was solved... If I click on search button, it shows  ---  Method not found: UserListActionImpl.retrieveName()"---- My command button action is... action="#{userListAction.retrieveName}"> --interface: public List<User> retrieveName(String firstName);--- implement class: public List<User> retrieveName(String firstName) {
            return userService.getAllUsers(firstName);
        } ---------------   Please give your assistance in this...

Thanks in advance --Mary

Comment: An action method should be a method which has no parameters and returns a string with the jsf-navigation-case. You mix two things here, the retrieval of the list and the navigation. I recommend to read http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/ and especially http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaql.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html to you. But the error itself causes in the invoke of retrieveName but you've got only a method with the signature retrieveName(String)

Comment: Thanks a lot to let me know this...